# iphone sdk: How to animate set of images in UIImageView using CoreAnimation?

Tags: iphone

I've set of images loaded in UIImageView. How to animate the images in UIImageView using CoreAnimation? Plz give me suggesstions

Comment: Exactly how do you want to animate them?

Comment: i want to animate repeatedly using thread. When i drag on the imageview,another set of images will be loaded and start animating the images. I did all in thread. but the animation is not smooth sometimes. How to bring smooth animation?

Answer (score 3):

it is very nice code for animating images with remaining time if you set the timer for alarm the images in animating according to the remaining sec of the timer i have used the images for make the flower

{

//-----------------image Animation-------------------//

```
-(void)imageAnimationMethod

   {

 imageAnimation=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 150, 135, 135)];


  [ self.view addSubview:imageAnimation];

 imageAnimation.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"101.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"102.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"103.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"104.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"105.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"106.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"107.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"108.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"109.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"110.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"111.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"112.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"113.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"114.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"115.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"116.png"],

                             nil];
```

//-----remaining is the second remaining of the timer---------//

```
  int i=remaining*16/16;


  imageAnimation.animationDuration=i;

  imageAnimation.animationRepeatCount=0;



 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just animate set of images in an imageView, the below code will help

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.gif"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.gif"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.gif"], nil];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

Comment: hi, I want to run the animation part in a thread. How to do that in a thread. How to do that?

Comment: Use CoreAnimation (CABasicAnimation), it runs in it own thread.